# protocol for the @ character in comments?

Tags: support, comments, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Ive seen a lot of comments where people put @name to specifically address a comment made by another user.  What is the protocol for this?  Is it used by SO in any way?

Should the full name be used after the @, or if its a multi word handle, is just the first enough?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the blog post announcing the feature.  All of your questions are answered there.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/

> There are some rules, of course:

> 1. This only works when referring to other people who have already commented.
>    2. Your comment must include @username that you are referring to, where “username” is a reasonable match to the user’s current display name (as seen in the comments above yours).
>    3. There must be a starts-with, case insensitive match of at least THREE characters to the displayname. So @a and @ab will never match anyone or anything.
>    4. Spaces are ignored in the match, so if the person’s display name is “Peter Smith” then just use @peter to match, or @petersmith.
>    5. Matching is performed in reverse chronological order, so if there are five people named “John” in the comments, writing “hey @john, have you considered apples?” will match the most recent John to comment.
>    6. Only one person can be replied to at a time in a comment. The first one in the string wins.
>    7. Users who have no display name set, whose faux-displayname is derived from their OpenID URL, cannot be matched.

Comment: @Clark Do you like apples?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this varies by user. Sometimes people use the full name, sometimes the first name, sometimes a shortening of the name (I get "eruc" and "eru" and even "e" sometimes), though a real shortening might not notify the user. This does seem to be the *de facto* means of addressing a previous comment, or the owner of the answer, or the owner of the question. As long as you don't change it to @jerk. :-)

Comment: It needs to be at least the first three letters, so the people using just "e" are doing it wrong

Comment: @michael: yeah, i've missed a couple...